# Analyzed memory dump shows only <Unresolved> references with DotMemory

Tags: docker, memory-leaks, amazon-ecs, dump, dotmemory

[image] I have a memory leak problem on a AWS dockerized microservice deployed with ECS. I wanted to analyze the dump with DotMemory so I used **exec** to connect to the container, **gcore** to save the dump and then transfer that dump to an **S3 bucket** so I could download it. Problem is, when I open the dump everything is "Unresolved" and I can't understand what's going on.

I've tried to run the same microservice locally and take a memory dump with Windows Task Manager and everything worked fine. Sadly, since is a complex system I can't replicate locally exactly what's happening when it's deployed so I need to create a readable dump from my deployed microservice. How do I fix the  issue?

Comment: Hello @MrDemien ! I have a similar issue (except the dump is made with dotnet-monitor as a sidecar). I updated the coredump_filter flag with 0x3f and did a new dump but no luck, everything is still "Unresolved" in DotMemory. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately. Have you tried with "0x8f"?

Comment: "0x3f" already set the first 6 bit to 1. The coredump_filter takes into account 8 bits max so we could try "0xff" to set every bit to 1 but in my case it shouldn't change anything. You can see in the following doc what each bit means: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html

Comment: I have create a way to [reproduce the issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DMRY-9646/NullReferenceException-when-reading-a-linux-dump-taken-with-dotnet-monitor-dump#focus=Comments-27-6737589.0-0) and JetBrains has created a [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DMRY-9990/All-types-are-unresolved-in-the-dump-file-taken-on-Linux-machine-even-if-coredumpfilter-is-set-to-0x3f)

Answer (score 0):

This issue might appear if the dump is missing the segments with metadata.

> Since kernel 2.6.23, the Linux-specific
> /proc/[pid]/coredump_filter file can be used to control which
> memory segments are written to the core dump file in the event
> that a core dump is performed for the process with the
> corresponding process ID.

See [core man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) section "*Controlling which mappings are written to the core dump*" for more information.

In order to get a proper dump of the dotNet process **coredump_filter** should be set to at least **0x3f**.

You can check what the current filter set for your process by executing:

```
cat /proc/<pid>/coredump_filter
```

To set the proper **coredump_filter** type:

```
echo "0x3f" > /proc/<pid>/coredump_filter
```

**<pid>** should be replaced with your process ID, for example:

```
echo "0x3f" > /proc/144/coredump_filter
```

### UPDATE: May 10, 2023

I've managed to collect a full dump with all the necessary information by using `createdump` utility:

```
createdump -u -f /tmp/coredump <pid>
```

The `-u` option tells `createdump` to generate a full memory dump, including all memory-mapped files. Note that this will result in a very large dump file for applications that use a lot of memory or have many memory-mapped files.

Example:

```
docker container exec -it \
  -u root --privileged \
  <container-id> \
  /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.16/createdump -u -f /tmp/coredump <pid>

docker cp <container-id>:/tmp/coredump .
```

Comment: I tried to set "0x3f" but I got the same result. Should I try with "0x8f"? It takes me quite sometime to try it because it's a 12Gb dump file.

Comment: There is a known issue with importing memory dumps taken in containers. Please, see the issue in JetBrains issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DMRY-9990